# two structs containing each other

Tags: c, struct

I have this code:

```
typedef struct
{
    node* dest;
} edge;

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    int visited;
    edge* edges[MAX_E];
} node;
```

So now `struct edge` have `node*`, and `struct node` have `edge*`, any one can explain to me how this work?

Comment: Each struct only saves a pointer (4 bytes, for example). You need to allocate each inear struct implictly..

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare (not define) one of the structs first

```
struct edge; // declare struct

struct node {
    char *name;
    int visited;
    struct edge *edges[MAX_E]; // array pf pointers
};
struct edge {
    struct node *dest;
};
```

Of course you can use `typedef` here. But I fail to see any advantage in using it, so my code stays clear of `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do it this way:

```
typedef struct node_s node;
typedef struct edge_s edge;

struct edge_s
{
    node   *dest;
};

struct node_s
{
    char   *name;
    int     visited;
    edge   *edges[MAX_E];
};
```

That way you can use the `typedef` names everywhere.

Note that neither `struct` contains an instance of the other.  Instead, they each contain pointers to the other.  So the dependency is just a matter of being able to access pointers to the types before they've been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's can't compile rigth away due to cross-definition of the structure.
You can fix that by adding the definition of the second structure before the first (like an opaque structure).

```
struct node;
```

Don't forgot to name your structure for that.

After that, it will do exactly what it was coded for : edge->dest is a "node" pointer and "node" have an egde pointer array.